# How to restore All Documents View

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, onedrive-for-business

With SharePoint Online, is there a way, within a SharePoint site, that a Site Collection Administrator can restore columns for an "All Documents" view if they have been dynamically changed?

In my case they were because I used the SharePoint migration tool to bring over some data from SharePoint 2013, back to OneDrive (SharePoint Online behind the scenes).  As a result my OneDrive column headers are different and represent headers from some files from SharePoint 2013.

I'm so frustrated because I had no idea that a SharePoint migration would jack up columns in the "All Documents" view, that powers OneDrive.

So my question, is there a way to restore/reset the All Documents view if its been dynamically modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on  my research and testing, the "**All Documents**" view cannot be restored in SharePoint, it is by design.